# Get value from an array of objects in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I am newly to iphone. I am working on an application where we need to calculate the value from an array of objects.

I have created a NSObject class "Catalogue", which includes catalogue_Value and catalogue_quantity. Now, suppose if we have two catalogue object in my array, then i need to calculate the total value.

here is my code :

```
int initialTotalPoints = 9999;
int totalUsedPoints = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<[arrayCheckout count];i++)
{
    Catalogue *catalog = [[Catalogue alloc] init];
    catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"checkout voucher %d is = %d*%d", i, catalog.catalogue_Value,catalog.catalogue_quantity);
    totalUsedPoints = catalog.catalogue_Value * catalog.catalogue_quantity;
}

initialTotalPoints = initialTotalPoints-totalUsedPoints;
```

The problem is due to the for loop, always it is taking "totalUsedPoints" of my last array object. But in actually, i need to add "catalog.catalogue_Value,catalog.catalogue_quantity" in my "totalUsedPoints" as per my total array objects. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing specific to objective c here. Every loop you are overwriting `totalUsedPoints` with a new value. You then do nothing with it, and it gets overwritten again. At the end of the loop it will only contain the last value assigned to it.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
totalUsedPoints += catalog.catalogue_Value * catalog.catalogue_quantity;
```

`+=` is equal to:

```
totalUsedPoints = totalUsedPoints + catalog.catalogue_Value * catalog.catalogue_quantity;
```

meaning it will be assigned with the previous value, plus the new value

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sum up quantity*value per catalog

```
int totalPoints = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<[arrayCheckout count];i++) {
    Catalogue *catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
    totalPoints += catalog.catalogue_Value * catalog.catalogue_quantity;
}
// totalPoints is now the sum of each arrays catalogue_Value*catalogue_quantity
```

You could check out [Blockskit](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/BlocksKit/2.2.3/), a nice package to make array iterations easier

Answer (score 0):

This is computer science 101 stuff, not unique to Objective-C. Others have already posted info on what you were doing wrong and how to fix it. I wanted to point out another flaw in your code. Take a look at these 2 lines:

```
Catalogue *catalog = [[Catalogue alloc] init];
catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
```

In the first line you create a new, empty Catalogue object and save a pointer to it in the variable `catalog`. In the very next line you fetch an object from your arrayCheckout object and save a pointer to it in your catalog variable. You end up discarding the object you created one line before.

This is like building a brand new car, putting it in front of your house, then junking it and fetching an existing car from a numbered parking space in a parking lot.

In ARC the empty Catalogue object you create in the first object will get deallocated on the very next line, so you aren't leaking memory, but it's pointless and wasteful to create an object that you immediately discard. (Memory allocation is one of the slowest tasks in an OS like iOS. It has to make a kernel call)

If your program was using manual reference counting then you would have leaked the Catalogue object. It would never get deallocated. Those two lines should read like this:

```
Catalogue *catalog;
catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
```

Or even as 1 line:

```
Catalogue *catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
```